# Converting a non-stationary random process into a WSS process by adding a random phase

Tags: digital-communications, power-spectral-density, random-process, stationary

Here is an example where this method has been implemented.

We were trying to calculate the spectrum of a transmitted signal(Random signal/weighted pulse)

1. The auto correlation function of the pulse which is not WSS because it is dependent on t:

[image]

2. We associated a random variable(which is the delay) with an uniform PDF with the signal:

[image]

3. PDF of the delay/the variable is:

[image]

I was unable to grasp the concept behind it, probably my basics are a bit rusty.

- By simply just associating a random variable (with an uniform PDF), how can we just make any random process a wide sense stationary process?
- Whats the concept behind it?

Comment: when you make everything in a text bold and/or italics, then that ceases to highlight anything; hence, I "normalized" your formatting.

Comment: But since we know nothing about the $P_T$, I don't think we can help you much. Define it! give context! Define what you mean with "associate"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that you can convert any non-stationary random process into a WSS random process by just adding a random phase. What *is* true is that you can make a (wide-sense) [cyclostationary process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclostationary_process) WSS by adding a random phase. A common example is the PAM process mentioned in your question:

$$x(t)=\sum_ka_kp(t-kT)\tag{1}$$

The discrete values $a_k$ in $(1)$ are assumed to be random. The process $x(t)$ can be shown to be cyclostationary. The modified process

$$\tilde{x}(t)=\sum_ka_kp(t-kT+\theta)\tag{2}$$

where $\theta$ is a random variable uniformly distributed on $[0,T]$ is WSS. This random phase reflects our uncertainty about the phase of the signal, i.e., about the origin of the time axis. In this sense, it is physically motivated, and not just a nice "trick" enabling us to compute the power spectrum of $(2)$.